# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'registerOnChange' on angular 6.1

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a kendo-multiselect control which is working on fine as separate controls on the form. As soon as I have put into Reactive Forms(through looping  of controls) Kendo_multiselect through error called:**Object doesn't support property or method 'registerOnChange'**

'mycomponent.html'

```html
<div class="card-body bg-light col-lg-10">
  <div formArrayName="significantAdults" *ngFor="let sigAdult of cdnForm.get('significantAdults').controls;  let j = index">
    <hr *ngIf="j>0" />     <!--add line to form-->
    <div [formGroupName]="j">
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="font-weight-bold col-sm-6 control-label" [attr.for]="'significantAdultDistricts'+j">District</label>
        <kendo-multiselect [data]="listDistrict" [textField]="'districtName'" [valueField]="'id'"
                           formControlName="significantAdultDistricts" class="form-control"
                           ></kendo-multiselect>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**mycomponent.ts**

This is the code it throws the onregisterchange error when I set the Formgroup and If I remove significantAdultDistricts And remaining all controls works fine.

```
const significantAdults = this.createsignificantAdultsForm(result.peopleCDNs);
 this.cdnForm.setControl('significantAdults', significantAdults);



createsignificantAdultsForm(significantAdults: any[]): FormArray {
    const formArray = new FormArray([]);
      significantAdults.forEach(sig => {
      if (sig.person.familyRole == "SignificantAdult") {
        formArray.push(this.fb.group({
          significantAdultId: sig.person.id,
          significantAdultLastName: sig.person.lastName,
          significantAdultFirstName: sig.person.firstName,
          significantAdultDateOfBirth: new Date(sig.person.dateOfBirth + 'Z'),
          significantAdultIDNumber: sig.person.idNumber,
          significantAdultDistricts: this.setDistricts(sig.person),
          //childDistricts: this.setDistricts(sig.person),
          significantAdultAlias: sig.person.alias,
          significantAdultAddress: sig.person.address,          
        }));
      }
    });
    return formArray
  }

  setDistricts(x) {
    let arr = new FormArray([])
    x.personDistricts.forEach(y => {
      arr.push(this.fb.group({
        id: y.district.id,
        districtName: y.district.districtName,
        sortOrder: y.district.sortOrder,
      }))
    })
    return arr;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please specify the browser you're testing the application?

Comment: Internet explorer 11 and chrome

Comment: Can you please provide Stackblitz reproduction of the issue?